# Antd v4.5.1 Setting initial values for Select

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms, antd

I have this code for handling status changes in my model.

```
<Form.Item 
     name="status"
     label="Status"
>
    <Select>
       {
           statusOptions
           ?
           Object.keys(statusOptions).map(statusId => {
               return <Select.Option key={ statusId } value={ statusId }>{ statusKey2Value(statusId) }</Select.Option>;
           })
           :
           null
       }
    </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

statusOptions is a JSON object as follows:

```
{
    0: Deleted
    1: Active
}
```

I am using Antd v4.5.1 which recommends handling initialValues directly within the Form component. I basically retrieve the data from the backend and provide the data to the Form component. However, when I try to set selected option for the dropdown, it is being displayed as "1" instead of "Active". I have found a solution provided by Antd Select API which is to hold status value as an object with a label value inside but I didn't really find it optimal to change my backend structure. Can anyone help me with this by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an `optionLabelProp="label"` on `Select` component and place a `label={statusOptions[statusId]}` on `Select.Option`. Oh and make `Select.Option` self-closing.

Comment: optionLabelProp is for rendering the content on selection, I think. When the page is loaded at first, it still displays as "1" instead of "Active".

Comment: Can you provide the Form component part of your code? I suspect there is something wrong with how you are setting initialValues prop

Comment: Note that since 4.2, you can now set initialValue prop directly on Form.Item. However, initialValues on form if set has hirer priority.

Comment: I do not set initialValues but I just run form.setFieldsValue({ ...res.data.item }) inside the function I fetch my data since I had problems setting initialValues. With the FormItem, I couldn't manage to prioritize it even if I have set initialValues to null.

Comment: Can you post console.log of res.data.item

Comment: { status: 1, _id: "5c233f713c5a80504368b9e3", ..., _v: 0 } with just bunch of strings except these.

Comment: So instead of using setFieldsValue after fetching, you create a state variable initialValues which you bind to the Form prop initialValues and update the state variable with the fetch data

Comment: Fetch -> setInitialValues(res.data.item) -> <Form initialValues={initialValues} ... />

Comment: Still the same problem this way, status is being displayed as 1.

Comment: initialValue={ (item && item.status ? item.status+"" : "") } - casting status to string interestingly solved it. Thanks for your help though.